# How to format a Google Chart used in a Google Site

Tags: google-visualization, google-sites

This seems like a very basic question, but nothing I've searched actually details the specific part I am hung up on.

I am trying to style a Google Chart that I have inserted into a Google Site.
I have read quite a bit of documentation about using JS to name classes and CSS to style elements when creating a chart, but how do I style a chart I have already inserted?

I don't see anywhere to edit the script that is populating the inserted chart.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: how did you _insert a chart into a Google Site_?